# Regular expressions: replace comma in string, Python

Tags: python, regex, string, replace

Somehow puzzled by the way regular expressions work in python, I am looking to replace all commas inside strings that are preceded by a letter and followed either by a letter or a whitespace. For example:

```
2015,1674,240/09,PEOPLE V. MICHAEL JORDAN,15,15
2015,2135,602832/09,DOYLE V ICON, LLC,15,15
```

The first line has effectively 6 columns, while the second line has 7 columns. Thus I am trying to replace the comma between (N, L) in the second line by a whitespace (N  L) as so:

```
2015,2135,602832/09,DOYLE V ICON LLC,15,15
```

This is what I have tried so far, without success however:

```
new_text = re.sub(r'([\w],[\s\w|\w])', "", text)
```

Any ideas where I am wrong?

Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The pattern you use, `([\w],[\s\w|\w])`, is *consuming* a word char (= an alphanumeric or an underscore, `[\w]`) before a `,`, then matches the comma, and then matches (and again, consumes) 1 character - a whitespace, a word character, or a literal `|` (as inside the character class, the pipe character is considered a literal pipe symbol, not alternation operator).

So, the main problem is that `\w` matches both letters and digits.

You can actually leverage lookarounds:

```
(?<=[a-zA-Z]),(?=[a-zA-Z\s])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bV0rN1/1)

The `(?<=[a-zA-Z])` is a positive lookbehind that requires a letter to be right before the `,` and `(?=[a-zA-Z\s])` is a positive lookahead that requires a letter or whitespace to be present right after the comma.

Here is a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Ur8YfF):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'(?<=[a-zA-Z]),(?=[a-zA-Z\s])')
test_str = "2015,1674,240/09,PEOPLE V. MICHAEL JORDAN,15,15\n2015,2135,602832/09,DOYLE V ICON, LLC,15,15"
result = p.sub("", test_str)
print(result)
```

If you still want to use `\w`, you can exclude digits and underscore from it using an opposite class `\W` inside a negated character class:

```
(?<=[^\W\d_]),(?=[^\W\d_]|\s)
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bV0rN1/2)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to describe your approach thoroughly! The way I understand it, [a-zA-Z] matched letters and [a-zA-Z\s] letters or whitespace. But why don't you have to use | to express an or statement? Secondly, what is the difference between "?<=" and "?="? Is it that it matches any letter (one or none characters) and any letter/whitespace (exactly one character)?

Comment: 1) I do not use `|` alternation symbol inside the [**character class**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) because it is not necessary, the alternation relationship is default inside a positive character class (that is, `[123]` matches either `1`, or `2`, or `3`). 2) The `(?<=...)` and `(?=...)` are [**lookarounds**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), please read the page at the link - these are used to check for some pattern presence, and if it is missing, no match occurs.

Comment: Thanks so much for the clarification! I used your regex expression and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

`\w` matches `a-z`,`A-Z` and `0-9`, so your regex will replace all commas. You could try the following regex, and replace with `\1\2`.

```
([a-zA-Z]),(\s|[a-zA-Z])
```

[Here is the DEMO.](https://regex101.com/r/xH6eV0/2)